# Fade In / Fade Out on Array of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to switch between two phone numbers on a mobile view.

I've got a `fade in` and `fade out` setup. I can log in the console what the HTML should be, However it's not switching to show what it should. It just stays put.

My jQuery function is as follows :

```
// Switch Phone Numbers On Mobile...
var html_array = [
    "<a href='tel:01'><span class='text-uppercase t-fsemibold t-white'>24 Hour </span><span class='t-white text-uppercase'>Emergency Helpline</span> <span class='t-dark t-fbold'>01</span></a>",
    "<a href='tel:02'><span class='text-uppercase t-fsemibold t-white'>Main </span><span class='t-white text-uppercase'>Office Number</span> <span class='t-dark t-fbold'>02</span></a>"
];

var index = 0;

(function animate(){
    $(".header-emergency__mobile").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        index = (index + 1) % html_array.length;
        console.log(html_array[index]);
        this.html = html_array[index];
    }).fadeIn(1000, animate);
})();
```

The HTML is as follows :

```
<div class="header-emergency header-emergency__mobile">
    <a href="tel:01"><span class="text-uppercase t-fsemibold t-white">24 Hour </span><span class="t-white text-uppercase">Emergency Helpline</span> <span class="t-dark t-fbold">01</span></a>
</div><!-- /.header-emergency -->
```

If I change the `this.html` to `this.text`, it just outputs the HTML. So I suspect I need to do some form of formatting, or my HTML is invalid.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: is the array a must have or is it something you implemented?

Comment: you'd better draw the two htmlelements, hide one and use toggle to toggle the visibility (or keep fade in and out)

Comment: Hi @LelioFaieta It's something I've implemented. No must have at all

Comment: then create two mirror divs with alternate content. Then set one as visibility hidden and use toggle to show one or the other

Comment: Like this idea, as I'm now hitting an issue where it's fading too quick and too often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
var html_array = [
    "<a href='tel:01'><span class='text-uppercase t-fsemibold t-white'>24 Hour </span><span class='t-white text-uppercase'>Emergency Helpline</span> <span class='t-dark t-fbold'>01</span></a>",
    "<a href='tel:02'><span class='text-uppercase t-fsemibold t-white'>Main </span><span class='t-white text-uppercase'>Office Number</span> <span class='t-dark t-fbold'>02</span></a>",
];
var index = 0;

(function animate() {
  $(".header-emergency__mobile").fadeOut(1000,function() {
    console.log("animate");
    index = (index + 1) % html_array.length;
    $(this).html(html_array[index]);
  }).fadeIn(1000, animate); 
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-emergency header-emergency__mobile">
  <a href="tel:01">
    <span class="text-uppercase t-fsemibold t-white">24 Hour</span>      <span class="t-white text-uppercase">Emergency Helpline</span>       <span class="t-dark t-fbold">01</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$(this).html(html_array[index]);
```

Comment: Or this.innerHTML = html_array[index]

Answer (score 1):

You need to have added the html content first to the body. Try to use display none if you need to hide it and later when the DOM is ready with the content loaded use the fadeIn and fadeOut.

Theses functions needs to be applied to html content that is already loaded. That's why you can't add the html content and fadeIn/Out in the same action.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="header-emergency header-emergency__mobile">
  <a href="tel:01">
    <span class="text-uppercase t-fsemibold t-white">24 Hour</span>      <span class="t-white text-uppercase">Emergency Helpline</span>       <span class="t-dark t-fbold">01</span>
   </a>
</div>
<div class="header-emergency header-emergency__mobile" style="visibility:hidden">
    <a href='tel:02'>
        <span class='text-uppercase t-fsemibold t-white'>Main </span><span class='t-white text-uppercase'>Office Number</span> <span class='t-dark t-fbold'>02</span>
    </a>
</div>

$('.header-emergency__mobile').toggle(1000);
```

For more info about toggle see [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Note that this is untested, can contain some code bugs but will demonstrate you how to approach this situation in an easy way